# Difference between Reference / Extension / NuGet Pacakge VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reference, nuget

What is the difference in VB.NET between

- a reference and (Solution Explorer > Right Click References > Add Reference)
- an extension (Menu Bar > Manage Extensions)
- a NuGet Package (Solution Explorer > Right Click References > Manage NuGet)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reference is another assembly that your project is aware of in order to access the types and members declared within it. For example, a Windows Forms Application project will reference the System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly by default, in order to access all the types relevant to Windows Forms.

An extension is a plug-in/add-in for Visual Studio that provides additional functionality not present in the IDE by default. Some are provided by Microsoft but are built separately to the VS IDE.

A NuGet package is a bundle of an assembly that your project can reference and/or other useful files the project can use. NuGet makes it simple to find and add references and other useful files through a common interface, rather than having to find, download and otherwise manage them yourself.